# Using MySQL server side prepared statement to improve app performance

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, database-performance, stored-functions

My situation:

- MySQL 5.5, but possible to migrate to 5.7
- Legacy app is executing single MySQL query to get some data (1-10 rows, 20 columns)
- Query can be modified via application configuration
- Query is very complex SELECT with multiple JOINS and conditions, it's about 20KB of code
- Query is well profiled, index usage fine-tuned, I spent much time on this and se no room for improvement without splitting to smaller queries
- With traditional app I would split this large query to several smaller and use caching to avoid many JOINS, but my legacy app does not allow to do that. I can use only one query to return results

My plan to improve performance is:

- Reduce parsing time. Parsing 20KB of SQL on every request, while only parameters values are changed seems ineffective
- I'd like to turn this query into prepared statement and only fill placeholders with data
- Query will be parsed once and executed multiple times, should be much faster

Problems/questions:

- First of all: does above solution make sense?
- MySQL prepared statements seem to be session related. I can't use that since I cannot execute any additional code ("init code") to create statements for each session
- Other solution I see is to use prepared statement generated inside procedure or function. But examples I saw rely on dynamically generating queries using CONCAT() and making prepared statement executed locally inside of procedure. It seems that this kind of statements will be prepared every procedure call, so it will not save any processing time
- Is there any way to declare server-wide and not session related prepared statement in MySQL? So they will survive application restart and server restart?
- If not, is it possible to cache prepared statements declared in functions/procedures?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the following will achieve your goal...

- Put the monster in a Stored Routine.
- Arrange to always execute that Stored Routine from the *same* connection.  (This may involve restructuring your client and/or inserting a "web service" in the middle.)

The logic here is that Stored Routines are compiled once per *connection*.  I don't know whether that includes caching the "prepare".  Nor do I know whether you should leave the query naked, or artificially prepare & execute.

Suggest you try some timings, plus try some profiling.  The latter may give you clues into what I am uncertain about.